Multilingual WordPress Website with multiple source languages
A very special request.
I'm developing a multilingual network for a client using WordPress. I've tried many plugins for my use case, but none have met my needs. The key feature of this network is to connect multilingual people and allow everything to be read in your own language. It includes an Activity Feed, Members, Groups, etc.
There are a lot of automatic translation plugins out there, but every plugin requires a source language. This means if I set English as the source language, an English visitor (Person A) posts something in English, and a German visitor (Person B) translates the whole page to German, he sees the translation of Person A's post, because the plugin knows it can translate from the source language (English) to German.
And here is the problem: I need this also reversed!
For example, if now Person B (German) posts something in German, I need Person A to be able to translate this German post into the source language (English). As mentioned earlier, most plugins require a source language to function properly, and nothing can be translated into the source language.
I've tried so many things, and the only option I'm currently satisfied with is a no-name plugin called Prisna-GWT, but it works with Google and has this ugly year 2007 top bar from Google when you translate something. On top of that, of course, it translates very poorly, which is why I would like to try a solution with DeepL.
Does anyone have an idea? I would like to somehow use DeepL, but there are no plugins out there that do not require a source language to work properly.
I hope my issue is understandable.
Thanks!

Perhaps add an option where each user can set their source language and then use gTranslate to run the translations for you.  I'd allow users to set their source language from within their profile.
